# Common Keyword Tag Not Available And Changing Tag Creation Requirements

Tags: support, tags, reputation, tag-creation-process

I was posting a question today on Stack Overflow about uninstalling a [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) extension.

When I went to enter some tags there was no tag for the word "Extension" and nothing really even close. And since my reputation points are less than 1,500 I couldn't create the tag, so I had to use Add-in instead.

I am curious, after all the millions of posts on SO why doesn't a tag as common as "Extension" exist?

Also, I don't particularly agree with the policy that you must have 1,500 reputation points to create a new tag. Surely they don't want to let brand new members make new tags, but how about lowering the requirement to something like 500?

They could also insert some logic into the new tag creation process to check whether a tag seems relevant to either the topic or within the scope of Stack Overflow's purpose (for example, technology questions).

This would prevent people from making tags like "Walmart" or making tags that match their company name to try and get some free advertising.

If they incorporated this tag logic into the site they could then lower the reputation requirements due to the lessened risk of people making irrelevant tags.

The tag "Extension" is clearly relevant and probably necessary, so I believe I should have been able to create it.

Comment: Such a tag would be too broad.

Answer (score 10):

I'm glad you weren't able to create it.

Not because the tag wasn't needed - but because a better tag already exists: [visual-studio-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-extensions)

This is better because it won't be confused with, say, [extension-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extension-methods) or [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) or any of those other extensions out there that have nothing to do with what you're asking about.

The search on the "Ask" page is pretty handy, but it returns a limited number of results and there are a *lot* of different sorts of extensions. If you're pretty sure the tag you want *should* exist and you're unable to find it, [go to the full tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and search for it there.

Comment: To emphasize something Shog is saying here; imagine a tag as something an expert in that topic will browse to seek questions to answer. Due to all the various things a tag like that could include, no true expert will peruse that tag. Or if they do, they'll see so many other posts on so many other topics.